# Colorize/highlight rails 3 'rake test' output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, colors, rake

I already use the `redgreen` gem to highlight some test output for rails 3.  I enjoy it, but I only found it because I was looking for a more specific solution, which it doesn't have.

I'd like to see the filenames highlighted specifically.  I'd like to illustrate with an example:

```
  4) Error:
test_shouldn't_be_able_to_make_duplicate_ModeratorPermission(ModeratorPermissionTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<ModeratorPermissionTest:0x7f13ad7ee3d0>
    /test/unit/moderator_permission_test.rb:10:in `test_shouldn't_be_able_to_make_duplicate_ModeratorPermission'

  5) Error:
test_*should*_be_able_to_make_duplicate_Post(PostTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<PostTest:0x7f13ad7f04a0>
    /test/unit/post_test.rb:12:in `test_*should*_be_able_to_make_duplicate_Post'

  6) Error:
test_should_be_able_to_make_a_post(PostTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<PostTest:0x7f13ad7f0478>
    /test/unit/post_test.rb:6:in `test_should_be_able_to_make_a_post'
```

When I first glance at this in black/white, my eyes don't immediately go to any one place.  I'd like to see "PostTest" and "ModeratorPermission" highlighted.  It'd also be nice if the test name itself was highlighted.

Does anyone know if there's a gem out there that does this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried term-ansicolor?

http://flori.github.com/term-ansicolor/

Or if you are just looking for cleaner output, maybe try turn?

https://github.com/TwP/turn

Comment: hm, it's been a while since I've done Ruby side tests for my rails apps.  I think with term-ansicolor, I could get what I was looking for.  Turn looks *really* sexy though.  I'll definitely try that when I get back to the point of testing my Rails app.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a little color on the `rake test` output, `gem install turn` works with ruby 1.9 and 2.0.